# What does/did a Postmaster do?

Tags: united-states, legislature

Reading the list of officers of the [59th Congress](http://history.house.gov/Congressional-Overview/Profiles/59th/), I see someone whose job I can't figure out:

> **Postmaster:**
>   J.C. McElroy

What did the Postmaster do? Was it his job to oversee the nation's postal service? There doesn't seem to be a corresponding position today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They ran the mail service for the *House of Representatives*, not for the country as a whole (that was, and still is, run by the Postmaster General). [The position was eliminated in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmaster_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives), with duties reassigned to other personnel.